# Login to Informix as a different user using dbaccess

Tags: shell, informix

I'm trying to write a shell script that when called, uses the dbaccess command line tool to pull data from a table.

```
echo "unload to data.csv delimiter '|' select * from tbl_extract;" | time dbaccess $database_name;
```

Now when I run this, it runs with my own account. Dbaccess seems to use the logged in Unix account to login to the database. But I want this to run under a different account. How do I get dbaccess to accept a username and password to use a different account?

Answer (score 1):

As @Johnathan Leffler correctly pointed out, if you use the `CONNECT` clause in the SQL, you cannot avoid being prompted for the password. What you need to do is ensure that the `dbaccess` process *itself* runs as a different user.

You can either use `sudo`, e.g.:

```
echo "unload to data.csv delimiter '|' select * from tbl_extract;" |\
    sudo -u __run_as_user__ time dbaccess $database_name;
```

NB You may need to configure the `sudoers` file to permit execution and not prompt for password.

The better alternative would be to [set `setuid` on the script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid), so that the whole script runs as `__run_as_user__`. This has the added bonus of ensuring any files (such as `data.csv`) are also owned by that user, and you don't run into permissions problems.

Comment: I have been trying use su, to run as a different user, once again the problem was with a password popping up. But what you are suggesting with setuid is promising. I will research on that. Thanks.

Comment: You won't get far with su. The key difference between su and sudo is that the latter can be configured to execute without a password.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the explicit `CONNECT` statement, and will need to provide the password:

```
{
echo "CONNECT TO $database USER 'whoever';"
echo "UNLOAD TO 'data.csv' DELIMITER '|' SELECT * FROM tbl_extract;"
} |
time dbaccess - -
```

Note the delicate balancing of quotes; the user name must be in a string, and you want to specify the database via a variable, so the string as a whole must be in double quotes and it is simpler to use single quotes around the name than backslash double quote `\"` twice (which would also work, even if the user name is in a variable).

This will prompt you for the user's password.

Alternatives include using `sudo` or `su` to change identity to the user.

My [SQLCMD](https://www.iiug.org/en/iiug-software-repository/#ESQL) program (unrelated to Microsoft's johnny-come-lately program of the same name) has a variety of ways of connecting to a database with a user name and scripting the password so that there is no interaction needed, ranging from the wholly insecure (command line argument; string in script) to the relatively secure (string in a file that can only be read by the user).  It can be used instead of DB-Access — I use it instead of DB-Access, but then I wrote it (mainly because I wasn't happy with the interface provided by DB-Access or its predecessor command).

Comment: Since I'm trying to create an automated job, is there any other why to avoid getting the prompt for password?

Comment: No; there's no way using DB-Access to avoid getting a prompt.  SQLCMD does provide such a mechanism.  It requires you to have ESQL/C (part of ClientSDK, not usually a problem) and a C compiler, but is (should be) otherwise straight-forward to install.  It has a Unix auto-configure script to do the heavy lifting.  If you're on a Windows environment, then the going is tougher — I've not ported SQLCMD to Windows recently (it's over a decade ago now that I last did it).  You could try messing with [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/); it would be able to drive DB-Access programmatically.